# How to get Listbox.selected item from Class in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've done a method that returns values from my "Person" class. I'm now trying to get a specific value from that class by selected item in the list and then be able to use that value. This is my code and the error i get is "Cannot convert  type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to". This is my Code:

```
       private Person aktuellPerson;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxPersoner.DataSource = Databasfunktioner.getPersoner();
        ListBoxPersoner.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListBoxPersoner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Error below Cannot convert  type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to 'Testgrupp2.Person'
        aktuellPerson = (Person)ListBoxPersoner.SelectedItem;       
        TextBoxFornamn.Text = aktuellPerson.Fornamn;
    }

}
```

And this is myclass

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Personnummer { get; set; }
    public string Fornamn { get; set; }
    public string Efternamn { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Personnummer + " " + Fornamn + " " + Efternamn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have also to make some changes in your binding mecanism

```
 private Person aktuellPerson;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxPersoner.DataSource = Databasfunktioner.getPersoner();
    ListBoxPersoner.DataValueField="PersonID";
    ListBoxPersoner.DataTextField="Fornamn";
    ListBoxPersoner.DataBind();
}

    protected void ListBoxPersoner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs )
   {
       var temItem= sender as DropDownList;  // if you are talking about DropDownList
        TextBoxFornamn.Text = temItem.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the input but, the name shows in the listbox but unfortunately it wont show in the textbox when selected when i tried this one

Comment: @mattias try what i change in my answer. use the sender to get the DropDownList

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear - SelectedItem returns a ListItem, not a Person.
You should post the code for the ListBoxPersoner class but i suspect you have the person name in the ListItem Text property and the person ID in the Value property.
If you don't have the person name in the ListItem you could use the Value to find the corresponding Person.
Again this is just speculation since i don't know the implementation of ListBoxPersoner.

Comment: Uhm okay, I've done the exact same thing in c# Windows forms application and it worked, now in asp.net Web forms it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert like this.

you need to create a Person Object and assign to some property.

```
protected void ListBoxPersoner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Person p = new Person();
       p.Fornamn = ListBoxPersoner.SelectedItem.ToString();       
        TextBoxFornamn.Text = p.Fornamn;
    }
```